# Memsize() and disksize() of an RDD in Spark

Tags: memory-management, apache-spark, rdd

I have an error which displays "No value found for SparkDriver" when I add it to a simple Spark program.

[Find size of data stored in rdd from a text file in apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179283/find-size-of-data-stored-in-rdd-from-a-text-file-in-apache-spark)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: SparkDriver.getContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {
override def onStageCompleted(stageCompleted: SparkListenerStageCompleted) {
  val map = stageCompleted.stageInfo.rddInfos
  map.foreach(row => {
      println("rdd memSize " + row.memSize)
      println("rdd diskSize " + row.diskSize)
   })
}})

Comment: I have an error when i try the Above code to get the memsize of the RDD in spark...

Comment: Please attach the error you got when you execute this code.